# Add Additional Logic To Node Save/Submit Process

Tags: 7, forms, theming

Where can I hook into drupal to modify the value of a specific field just before it is inserted into the database?

For example, lets say I wanted to trigger an email or run an arbitrary piece of code just before the node is inserted into the database?

I've been looking at hook_node_presave and it looks like it will do what I want, but I need it to only apply to one content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use either [hook_entity_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7), [hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) [hook_field_attach_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_presave/7). These hooks are all pretty similar right now. Actually not sure why there are 3 of them :)

Simply add a check for the content type and/or the existense of the field you want to alter.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.

For searchers: 
`function hook_node_presave($node) {
    if ($node->type == 'node_machine_name' && $node->is_new === TRUE) {
        //Logic Here
    }
}`

Comment: Looks good, feel free to edit that directly into my answser (yeah, you can do that, someone with more points just needs to approve it afterwards). That's much more readable than in a comment.